# SQL Query to count entire duplicate row

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I am looking for help with a query to do the following:

Before the insert of a row, find how many rows in 2 tables have the same information as is being inserted. 
So basically I am looking to see if this row will be a complete duplicate. 
I want to base this on all the columns, not just the PK, because if there is even one column different then this is a valid insert.

This is something along the lines of what I need, although incorrect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ORDER_TRF_HEADER
WHERE
((SELECT * FROM ORDER_TRF_HEADER_COMPLETE WHERE MA_PONUM = '29608207') = (SELECT * FROM ORDER_TRF_HEADER WHERE MA_PONUM = '29608207'));
```

Table - ORDER_TRF_HEADER

`MA_CUST    VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
MA_PONUM    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
MA_ODATE    VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
MA_ITEMS    NUMBER(3,0)
MA_SALEM    VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
MA_PDAYS    NUMBER(3,0)
MA_CURR VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)`

Table - ORDER_TRF_HEADER_COMPLETE

`MA_CUST    VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
MA_PONUM    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
MA_ODATE    VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
MA_ITEMS    NUMBER(3,0)
MA_SALEM    VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
MA_PDAYS    NUMBER(3,0)
MA_CURR VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)`

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: To me, this sounds like a bad way to do things, but think about declaring a unique constraint on "all the columns minus the primary key".

Answer (score 1):

> I want to base this on all the columns, not just the PK, because if there is even one column different then this is a valid insert.

then your issue is that you have NOT defined your primary key correctly.

Certainly there are good reasons for not maintaining a primary key consisting of every attribute in the record, however a better solution than checking for duplicates in such a clumsy way before inserting would be to maintain a has of the data as a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `INTERSECT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   order_trf_header_complete
        WHERE  ma_ponum = '29608207'
        INTERSECT
        SELECT *
        FROM   order_trf_header
        WHERE  ma_ponum = '29608207') ;
```

**Note:**: You  better use all column names explicitly instead of select `*`